# filter coredumps collected by systemd

Tags: systemd, core-dump

Is is possible to filter the coredumps collected by `systemd-coredump`?

- I do not want `/var/lib/systemd/coredump/` to be filled up from executables in user writable locations
- coredumps of software from `/bin` or `/usr` should be collected